# Integrate AngularJS template with HTML landing page template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, templates

I already have a landing page HTML5 based that I bought the template and made my own adjusts.
Now I'm planning to bought a AngularJS Dashboard template to using together with my Landing page template. But I don't know how I can integrate. Each template has the own javascript files, and folder structure. One is HTML5 based and the another one is AngularJS based.
I'm thinking to create a folder in my landing page structure called 'app', and put all my angular template there. But I don't know if this is correct.

Which is the best way to integrate these projects ?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML5 based"? Does it use just javascript, or also incorporate the JQuery library? Angular is a framework that uses JQuery unless it's not available where it then falls back on JQLite (A lighter version of jquery). So it sounds to me like you would just add the angular reference to your existing landing page along with your Angular templates and you're good to go.

Comment: @ChrisW. I'm using this HTML5 template for the landing page : http://themeforest.net/item/porto-responsive-html5-template/4106987
And I want to use a AngularJS template for my dashboard. like one of theses : http://www.responsivemiracle.com/best-responsive-html5-angularjs-templates/
Each one has a differente folder structure. The landing page use a lot of different javascript libraries that don't are used in the angularJS template.